# Using rspec failed tests (to map the program out) is resulting in errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

Note: I'm following a tutorial for Ruby on Rails, and thus I'm a complete noob

Basically, in the tutorial I am following, it shows you how to make failed tests that you meet as you go along, like a checklist for your program. My problem is that when I do the test, it *sort of* outputs what it should, but in errors, which isn't good (I think) because it doesn't match the output of the instructions.

Output: http://pastebin.com/0xyf3aBf (and show below)

**Output**

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mexpect(page).to have_content('Sample App')←[0m

       ←[31mexpected #has_content?("Sample App") to return true, got false←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top
(required)>'←[0m

Finished in 0.07 seconds
←[31m1 example, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7←[0m ←[36m# Static pages Home p
age should have the content 'Sample App'←[0m

Randomized with seed 10853
```

My static_pages_specs.rb file: http://pastebin.com/L0LHACR4 (and shown below)

**static_pages_specs.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you not just add the code here?

Comment: I don't understand the question, since I can't see the "output of the instructions". Nor do we know the versions of anything you're using, what tutorial you're following, and so on. In short, there's nothing to do yet.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the extra control codes (which might just be a symptom from your console or the cut&paste), this looks like a normal test failure. Which you should expect if you have written the test first.

One important part of TDD is indeed to get a simple failing test - with this kind of failure (the `have_content` matcher has failed to match) - and to then "fix" the failure.

It is also possible to get problems with the test code, which would also need fixing of course. But I don't see anything wrong with your test in this case.

If there was something wrong with the test, you would have to debug it in the more traditional way of applying critical thinking and experience when you read the code. So try to keep the test code simple, and to the point. Break down long complex tests into many short small ones.

Possibly the `have_content` matcher could be improved to give better context, rather than make a sub-test that you were not aware of . . . that was written by someone else though, and isn't too bad, it still makes some sense (there is presumably no content at all on the target page).

Comment: while this is good advice, he's following a specific tutorial and having a failing test.

Comment: @sevenseacat: I *think* the OP is following TDD, and has not implemented the feature under test yet.

Comment: I haven't. The tutorial is currently teaching TDD, so the errors are normal. I just saw a different output, and was wondering what the heck was wrong. By the way, is there any way to omit the control codes? This is the command I am using => bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Comment: @user3029002: I think the control codes are colour controls, you can omit them by doing `bundle exec rspec --no-color spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` - there may also be a default options for rspec set up somewhere which has `-c` or `--color` in it - removing that should also remove the colour codes. You could also research what would be required to support ANSI colour codes on your terminal (I'm guessing Windows cmd?)

Comment: I'm on windows 7 using git bash.